# Syntax Error: ON RIGHT when trying to match a substring in Impala

Tags: sql, substring, impala

Does anyone know why I am receiving this error? I am using SQL in IMPALA and it  wont run. Theres a yellow underline under mem_register_hsty_view and transparency_services_summary_2018.

Here is my code:

```
use sndbx_dx;

SELECT
    r.member_identifier,
    n.fst_nme
FROM mem_register_hsty_view n
JOIN transparency_services_summary_2018 r
    ON RIGHT(TRIM(r.member_identifier),4) = LEFT(n.fst_nme,4)
ORDER BY
    r.id_key,
    r.group_number,
    n.fst_nme;
```

Here is the error:

> AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1:undefined: ...ervices_summary_2018 r ON RIGHT(TRIM(r.member_identifi... ^ Encountered: RIGHT Expected: CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, NOT, NULL, REPLACE, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Answer (score 0):

From the current Impala [documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_string_functions.html) the functions for taking some number of characters from the left or right of the string appear to actually be `STRLEFT` and `STRRIGHT`, respectively.  Apply this to your current query gives:

```
SELECT
    r.member_identifier,
    n.fst_nme
FROM mem_register_hsty_view n
INNER JOIN transparency_services_summary_2018 r
    ON STRRIGHT(TRIM(r.member_identifier), 4) = STRLEFT(n.fst_nme, 4)
ORDER BY
    r.id_key,
    r.group_number,
    n.fst_nme;
```